# Graph Delta Query on Groups not returning expected changes

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

After making a change to a Group in Azure AD using Microsoft Graph API v1 (for example, Adding a user to the group) which completes successfully, if the Group Delta Query is fired immediately after the change, the graph delta query doesn't return the expected delta, instead, have to do Group delta query again after some time to get the expected change.

What is the expected latency between any mutating operation using Microsoft Graph API and consequentially getting the same change in Delta Query's result?

Comment: I have tried adding, deleting users from the group.  I see very slight latency of ~8 - 10 seconds using the delta query.  Are you seeing more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Security Groups are pretty lightweight, Unified Groups have a number of additional dependencies (i.e. a mailbox if it's mail-enabled, the group's Drive, etc.). As such, it takes a little longer to provision them. In general, this process takes 10 seconds or less to complete but it *can* take a bit longer (anecdotally, it seems to depend on how much other activity/load is on the tenant at the time).

My general guidance here would be to assume 20 seconds. I have a number of integration tests that exorcize Group creation/deletion that include a 20 second and I've yet to have a test fail due to this latency.